# Lauterbach - load two elf files but keep both symbols

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm going to load several elf-fils into TRACE32 and onto the chip.
But Lauterbach only keeps the symbols of the last uploaded elf file.
How can I change the behavior?

Answer (score 6):

`data.load.elf` clears all symbols. To prevent TRACE32, tell it to refrain from doing so.

use:

```bash
# clear all existing symbols
data.load.elf path\to\myfirst.elf
# additionally load symbols without clearing existing ones.
data.load.elf path\to\mysecond.elf /noclear
```